# Irregular execution time of Flask app on GCloud App Engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask

I have built a webscraping API and wrapped as a Flask app, and have deployed to Google Cloud's App Engine. My code works just fine, but am encountering irregular execution duration when the API is called, ranging from 1s to 250s.

The APIs are called via a scheduled pubsub Cloud Function on an hourly basis, and here are the logs of the API calls to the Flask App.
[image]

The scraping code only goes to one webpage to scrape selected information, here is the code:

```
//Entry function in main.py
@app.route('/scrape',  methods=['GET'])
def scrape():
    scraper = Scraper()
    response_object = scraper.get_all_chapters(request)
    return jsonify(response_object)

//The get_all_chapters() function
def get_all_chapters(self, request):

    url = constants.url
    contents = self.get_url_content(url, headers=self.headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')

    handbooks = soup.findAll('ul', {'id': [
        'item_0',
        'item_1'
    ]})

    chaps = []
    for handbook in handbooks:
        chapters = handbook.findAll('li', {'class': 'box'})

        for chapter in chapters:
            a_tag = chapter.find('a')
            if a_tag != None:
                chap_url = a_tag.attrs['href']
                chap_title = a_tag.text.strip()

                chap = {
                    'title': chap_title,
                    'url': chap_url
                }

                chaps.append(chap)              

    response_object = {}
    response_object['statusCode'] = 200
    response_object['chapters'] = chaps
    return response_object

//app.yaml
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 300

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Running the above code locally on my machine usually do not take more than 2s. Is there something wrong with my code or settings?

Comment: I suspect this is partly due to VM / container startup time, and partly due to whatever it is your application is scraping. Have you tried setting a `min_num_instances` attribute to your app.yaml to see whether this reduces response time?

Comment: @ChristopherP Thanks for your response. I have not set `min_num_instances`, but by observing the instances graph on App Engine, there are at most 2 instances. Is 2 instances considered too little (or reasonable) for a webscraping job? The website that I am scraping is js loaded.

Comment: Can you include all of `main.py`? Seems like there is something slowing down the initialization of your app.

Comment: Setting min_num_instances means that there will always be an available instance to handle requests, so you avoid the time cost of having to spin up a new instance when a request comes in. Meanwhile, you should investigate possible causes of slow initialization or execution in your code